# What can be the cause of "use of undeclared identifier LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE" message

Tags: ios, cocoalumberjack

I'm trying to configure cocoalumberjack and when I've added `ddLogLevel` set to `LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE` XCode throws "use of undeclared identifier" error. Why is that? How to avoid?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611341/prefix-pch-not-included-at-compilation-time) indicates that clearing `DerivedData` and restarting Xcode solves this kind of error.

However you should not include variables in the pre-compiled header as it will be included in every source file and prefix files are somewhat complicated compared to normal header files.

Better is to have use a `Constants.h` file which contains:

```
extern int ddLogLevel;
```

and `#import` that into your prefix file.

Then create an `Constants.m` with:

```
int ddLogLevel =
#ifdef DEBUG
                 LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#else
                 LOG_LEVEL_ERROR;
#endif
```

This way there is only one instance of `ddLogLevel` and it can be easily changed at runtime if necessary.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845211/ios-prefix-pch-best-practices) for hints about prefix file *best practices*.

Comment: I think it's now DDLogLevelVerbose

Comment: @Droppy But ddLogLevel is used by DDLogError and that kind of macros, that is, is used along all the program. Is not in that case better to add it in the PCH? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo Well it can be *declared* in the precompiled header (using `extern`) but should be *defined* in a single source file.

Answer (score 6):

What solved it for me was changing `#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>` to `@import CocoaLumberjack;`, when using Xcode 8.0 for an Objective-C project.

Comment: I am using Cocoapods

Comment: i changed to *@import CocoaLumberjack;* but got error Module 'CocoaLumberjack' not found

Answer (score 2):

Droppy’s post is correct and I recommend doing that, but I would like to address the question directly. There is a flaw in your code that may be resulting in the error.

`LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE` is defined in `DDLog.h`. Your header file only imports `DDLog.h` if `__OBJC__` is defined, but uses `LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE` without this condition. Therefore if `__OBJC__` is not defined, `LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE` will be undefined.

Why would `__OBJC__` not be defined? The prefix header is prepended to C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ files. Since `__OBJC__` is only defined for the latter two, if there are any C or C++ files in your project then the error will occur.

Knowing this, it is clear the `ddLogLevel` definition should be inside the `#ifdef __OBJC__` check. However, you should do what Droppy said, and also make sure all Objective-C imports go inside the check.

Answer (score 1):

For people who use "CocoaLumberjack 2.X" and still facing same issue after pod update, please try to import "DDLegacyMacros.h".

For prefix file users, try something like this :

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
...
...
    #import <DDTTYLogger.h>
    #import <DDLog.h>
    #import <DDLegacyMacros.h>
#endif
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I imported CocoaLumberjack as framework and I' getting this error: "use of undeclared identifier ddloglevel". I add it #import "DDLegacyMacros.h" but I'm getting this error "DDLegacyMacros.h file not found"